# What is crystal, resonator, crystal resonator, crystal oscillator?

Tags: oscillator, crystal

After browsing different online electronic stores, I got a little bit confused with crystals...

1. What's the proper name for this:
   [image: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:16MHZ_Crystal.jpg]
   Crystal? Quartz crystal? Resonator? Quartz crystal resonator? Oscillator? Crystal Oscillator?
2. This one have the same function as what I posted on #1 but less accuracy and stability?
   [image: i00.i.aliimg.com/photo/247949494/Ceramic_resonator.jpg]
   Is it called Resonator? Ceramic resonator? Ceramic crystal? Oscillator?
3. This is the same as #2 but have two ceramic capacitors built in?
   [image: i01.i.aliimg.com/wsphoto/v0/1122545575/5-x-Radial-Lead-20-000-MHz-font-b-Ceramic-b-font-font-b-Resonator-b.jpg]
   So what do you call it?
4. What do you call these:
   [image: www.token.com.tw/resonator/image/resonator-ztb500e.jpg]
5. This is the schematic symbol for #1?
   [image: upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cb/Crystal-oscillator-IEC-Symbol.svg]
   What about for #2, #3 and #4?
6. This is a crystal oscillator? Can I replace The "Crystal" with #2/#3/#4??
   [image: letsmakerobots.com/files/userpics/u1533/4MHz_crystal_oscillator_.jpg]

Comment: You should break this up into separate questions.

Comment: @JYelton  It's okay as is.  We'll end up with who-is-who of  crystal/oscillator/resonator.

Comment: @Nick Sounds good, then. You might want to shrink some of the inline images, though.

Comment: Related, somewhat duplicated: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/36308/2028

Comment: @JYelton
Actually, I have read that before I posted this, but I got a bit more confused when I've read from wikipedia about Oscillator and they called the crystal as quartz crystal resonator. So I posted this along with other questions in my head

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Crystal, or quartz crystal. Crystal resonator is not at all incorrect but they have been called just crystals for over 50 years to no harm...
2. Ceramic resonator; maybe just resonator, but certainly not crystal or oscillator.
3. Basically yes. (The middle terminal will be ground). However there are also ceramic *filters* with this configuration, so be careful and double check the datasheet. (Especially if they are marked with common radio IF frequencies, 455 kHz or 10.7 MHz!)
4. I don't know; most likely no.2 in different packaging, I have never seen quartz crystals packaged this way.
5. Yes.
6. No, though connected to the right pins on an IC it might be. A crystal oscillator is either:

   a. something like package (1) with 4 pins; it takes 3.3V or 5V in, and puts out a clean signal (making it dead easy to use), or

   b. a circuit involving these components, possibly a resistor, and some kind of amplifier (inside the IC, or a separate transistor) or a misused logic gate, to drive the crystal. 
   In the latter case you can usually substitute a ceramic resonator, but you may have to change the capacitors and a gain setting resistor (or drive limiting resistor) to make it work at all, or work reliably.

Comment: Thanks. I've seen #4 from a tv remote control. I thought it was a capacitor.. LOL